# heroku nodered can't install modules

Tags: heroku, node-red

I'm trying to install the node-red-contrib-telegrambot and node-red-contrib-uuid modules in nodered in heroku and I get an error:

```
ERR! engine Not compatible with your version of node/npm: follow@0.11.4
npm ERR! notsup Required: {"node":"0.10.x || 0.8.x"}
```

How to fix this error?

I did not install other modules here, these are the first ones.
Tried redis - same error
Although locally I had no problems with these modules.

BuildLogID:
Building on the Heroku-20 stack
Determining which buildpack to use for this app
Node.js app detected

Resolving node version 16.x
Downloading and installing node 16.14.2
Using default npm version: 8.5.0

Comment: Some details about how you installed/setup Node-RED and what versions you NodeJS, npm and the nodes.

Comment: @hardillb, installed using the link https://elements.heroku.com/buttons/joeartsea/node-red-heroku, via the "Deploy" button.
Node-RED v2.2.2
How to check NodeJS version in heroku and npm don't know

Comment: Node-RED will log the version of NodeJS it's using in the first few lines on start up. Also what other nodes have you already installed as neither of the nodes you mention have that engine restriction? (Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71910131/edit) the question when adding details)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the [follow](https://www.npmjs.com/package/follow) which is used for tracking changes in CouchDB databases.

Neither of those 2 modules you are trying to install appear to make use of this module in any of their dependencies this must be being driven by something else.

If you examine the dependencies of the `node-red-heroku` installer it has `nano@~5.11.0` which is what is pulling in the old version of `follow` with the outdated `follow` version.

You need to raise this as an issue with against node-red-heroku on it's git hub page: https://github.com/joeartsea/node-red-heroku

In the meantime the error shouldn't actually stop you installing and using the nodes you want.

Answer (score 0):

I dug into what @hardiilb was saying earlier in their answer, and digging further into my issue which I believe was very similar to yours:

1. This issue **was** inhibiting my NR server's ability to install nodes, let alone nodes that should have been installed by default like the `email` node (which was broken out of the core for some very strange reason)
2. Attempting to update any of the nodes via palette manager was **absolutely** **failing** because of this same error babbling about engines or whatever.

**Fix [so far]**

I deleted the `"nano": "~10.x",` kvp and then I *added* all the npm modules that Node-RED was complaining about as *dependencies* in the `package.json` file like this:

```
// fork of the joersarta/node-red repo
{
    "name"         : "node-red-heroku",
    "version"      : "0.1.0",
    "dependencies": {
        "when": "~3.x",
        "pg": "^8.3.0",
        "feedparser":"~0.19.2",
        "redis":"~0.10.1",
        "node-red": "~3.0.2",
        "node": "~18.11.0",
        "@sentry/node":"~7.16.0",
        "@sentry/tracing":"~7.16.0",
        "jsonschema":"~1.4.1"
    }
}
```

Once I did that and deployed this branch I had made this change on, I was able to start using node-red and loading both custom nodes as well as custom modules with the `function` node as expected.